# Using telerik's RadAjaxManager with nested ASCX controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, telerik, radajaxmanager

I want to use telerik's RadAjaxManager with nested ASCX controls

I have the following setup:

```
Page
   ascx1
     ascx2
```

ascx2 is nested in ascx1 which is in Page.

I have a RadAjaxManager on 'Page'.
From a control in ascx2, I invoke a javascript method which calls

```
ajax.ajaxRequest(arguments);
```

The problem is that it runs

```
protected void AjaxManager_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
```

in ascx1 and not the one in ascx2 --

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you child controls you should use the:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
```